# Three JS : Attaching an object to another

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to attach a cube to another cube at a specific point. I'm able to get collision and .add() is working fine. However, I want to add child cube exactly at point where collision occurs to the parent cube.

```
for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < MovingCube.geometry.vertices.length; vertexIndex++) {       
  var localVertex = MovingCube.geometry.vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
  var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4( MovingCube.matrix );
  var directionVector = globalVertex.sub( MovingCube.position );
  var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize() );
  var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects( collidableMeshList );

  if ( collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length() )             
console.log(" Hit and collision detected " + SELECTED);
MovingCubeBig.add(SELECTED);

      // Is there way to get collision point and attach object at that point?


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Intersections results should include a `point` attribute.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Raycaster.js#L255

Maybe you can use this to attach the child at the right position ?

Also, this example may help http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_terrain_raycast

Comment: In my case, I have big cube and small cube. The collision occurs from big cube's perspective, that means, big cube receives collision from small cube. Is the point is relative to the object collided (small cube)? Or is it the point where the collision occurred (on big cube)?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you ask, sorry.
I think it's a global coordinates, in the same referential as your `originPoint`, and probably as your cubes positions.

hth